# What is the best way to get the 'Request' object in the controller?

Tags: symfony

I have seen the request object being passed to the controller action method as a parameter like this:

```
public function addAddressAction(Request $request)
{
    ...
}
```

I have also seen it within the action method where it is gotten from the container:

```
public function addAddressAction()
{
    $request  = $this->getRequest();
    ...
}
```

Which one is better? Does it matter?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you take a deeper look at [the Symfony2 Base Controller code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php), you may notice that `getRequest()` is marked as deprecated since version 2.4 and will be removed in 3.0.

```
/*
 * ...
 * @deprecated Deprecated since version 2.4, to be removed in 3.0. Ask
 *             Symfony to inject the Request object into your controller
 *             method instead by type hinting it in the method's signature.
 */
public function getRequest()
{
    return $this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();
}
```

Introduced by the following evolution,

- [[FrameworkBundle] use the new request_stack service to get the
  Request object in the base Controller class.](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/2e07338c5c58184318812f3852766a961b973df9)

And, [here's](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md#frameworkbundle) the [upgrade from 2.x to 3.0 documentation](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md).

- [Upgrade from 2.x to 3.0 - FrameworkBundle](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md#frameworkbundle)

**Conclusion,**

Your Request should then be part of your action's signature.

Comment: I thank you for your excellent answer, indeed getting the request from the container is marked as deprecated.

Answer (score 14):

As far as I know there's no difference. It doesn't interrupt affect much either way. Even if you want to specify required parameters in your action. E.g.

```
/**
 * @Route("/edit/{id}", name="edit")
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    // Both $request and $id are available
}
```