# Symfony2 how to inject request and get route parameters in controller

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, request, inject

My controller method looks following:

```
   /**
     * @Route("/film/{slugDe}", name="movie_De")
     */
    public function movieAction($slugDe)
    {
```

now I need to bind a form with request, but request is not injected. How do I inject request and keep the route parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could get the request like this from within the controller...

```
$request = $this->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();
```

Edit:

Actually, after thinking about this a bit, I think Martin's answer might be the better route to take. While the above is a perfectly valid way to get the request from the controller, type-hinting for the request is probably the preferred method. And as shown, you can still type-hint for the request in your controllers action method when you're using slugs.

[What is the best way to get the 'Request' object in the controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984816/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-the-request-object-in-the-controller)

http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack

Answer (score 2):

You can simply inject request like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

public function movieAction($slugDe, Request $request)
{
    // ...

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    // ...
}
```

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#the-request-as-a-controller-argument